# SBT: How to get all Definitions in IntegrationTest?

Tags: scala, sbt

It is easy to get all instances of `TestDefinition` in `IntegrationTest`:

`val tests: Seq[TestDefinition] = (definedTests in IntegrationTest).value`

But how do I get all instances of `xsbti.api.Definition` in `IntegrationTest`? It used to be possible to do this:

```
val defs: Seq[Definition] = {
  val analysis = (compile in IntegrationTest).value
  analysis.apis.internal.values.flatMap(_.source.api.definitions)
}
```

(for example, for filtering tests based on the suite annotations: say, `@RequiresCassandra` or `@RequiresCluster` and so on). But `analysis.apis` has been removed--not sure when, but it's absent in SBT 1.3.8. I haven't found any documentation on what to use instead.

One of SBT's chief strengths, compared to such XML-based tools like Maven, is the ability to define build settings programmatically. It should be possible to filter tests based on anything in the test code itself, not only on test names. I can't believe something so useful—something that really places SBT above competitors—could be just removed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Tests.allDefs`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main-actions/src/main/scala/sbt/Tests.scala#L417) returns [`Definition`](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/f2bb3115dd8459df9e2cd06143c2ce779cd1ba00/internal/compiler-interface/src/main/contraband-java/xsbti/api/Definition.java#L7)s given [`CompileAnalysis`](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/f2bb3115dd8459df9e2cd06143c2ce779cd1ba00/internal/compiler-interface/src/main/java/xsbti/compile/CompileAnalysis.java#L26). For example,

```
val analysis: CompileAnalysis = (compile in IntegrationTest).value
val definitions: Seq[Definition] = Tests.allDefs(analysis)
val annotations: Seq[Annotation] = definitions.flatMap(_.annotations())
```

There was a [change](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2478) back in 2016 from

```
val compile = TaskKey[Analysis]("compile", "Compiles sources.", APlusTask)
```

to

```
val compile = TaskKey[CompileAnalysis]("compile", "Compiles sources.", APlusTask)
```

where

```
trait Analysis extends CompileAnalysis {
  ...
  val apis: APIs
  ...
}
```

so now we have to cast to [`Analysis`](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/f2bb3115dd8459df9e2cd06143c2ce779cd1ba00/internal/zinc-core/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/inc/Analysis.scala#L30)

```
analysis match { case analysis: Analysis => ... }
```

which is what `allDefs` does.